# How do I resolve this dependency issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm using a Website in C# ASP.Net and using the Strip Nuget package. I've updated to the latest nuget packages and am now getting the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have checked my web.config file and have, what looks like, the correct bindingRedirect details in there

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

but I'm still getting the error about needing Version 9.0.0.0. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You could try adding a direct dependency to `Newtonsoft.Json` and choose the correct version

Comment: Can I have the latest version AND 9.0.0.0?

Comment: Are you using `Newtonsoft.Json` in your own code? If so, then my suggestion might be a problem, unless your own code will work with version 9.0.0.0

Comment: Make sure you are putting it in the right place. Sometimes there is more than one [assemblyBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/assemblybinding-element-for-runtime) element (with a different `appliesTo` attribute).